# Stored procedure - do not execute if any part of the procedure fails

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

**SQL Server 2008**

I have a stored procedure that selects data from a source, inserts it into a staging table, deletes some rows from the fact table and then inserts more rows from the staging table into the mentioned fact table.

I would like to not execute the procedure if ANY part of the code fails. So for example if deletion of the rows fail because of some reason I would like to have the stage table also unchanged.

Is it possible? To 'check' the code and insert tables before running the code?

Edit: thank you! I implemented one of the solutions you suggested. The thing is I have a procedure nested in another procedure (try catch nested in another try catch) - I want to catch the errors and insert them to the errorlog table I created. The error catching worked as expected before but after the changes errors are not inserted to the table anymore and I'm getting the error:
*The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction.*

The query I'm running is the MAIN procedure (below)

the structure of my first query is:

```sql
[procedure instertdata]
BEGIN TRANSACTION 

BEGIN TRY

  INSERT INTO Your_Table (Col1, Col2)
  VALUES ....

  UPDATE Your_Table 
  SET [Col1] = .......
  WHERE ........

  COMMIT TRANSACTION 

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
INSERT INTO MyErrorLogTable
  SELECT  AffectedTable = 'mytable',
         ERROR_NUMBER()    AS ErrorNumber,
         ERROR_SEVERITY()  AS ErrorSeverity,
         ERROR_STATE()     AS ErrorState,
         ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
         ERROR_LINE()      AS ErrorLine,
         ERROR_MESSAGE()   AS ErrorMessage,
         GETDATE()      AS TimeAndDate;

  IF @@trancount > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

END CATCH
```

and the code of the main procedure is:

```sql
[procedure main]

BEGIN TRY

EXEC [procedure instertdata]

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

 INSERT INTO MyErrorLogTable
   SELECT  ProcedureName= 'mytable',
         ERROR_NUMBER()    AS ErrorNumber,
         ERROR_SEVERITY()  AS ErrorSeverity,
         ERROR_STATE()     AS ErrorState,
         ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
         ERROR_LINE()      AS ErrorLine,
         ERROR_MESSAGE()   AS ErrorMessage,
         GETDATE()      AS TimeAndDate;
END CATCH
```

What I'm doing wrong? How to handle it?

EDIT:
I mentioned before I have a procedure nested in another one. What I did I moved the transaction rollback to the outer one. The MAIN procedure doesn't have transaction rollback.. procedure is nested So it looks like follows:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[myload] 
AS
BEGIN

 set nocount on;
    declare @trancount int;
    set @trancount = @@trancount;
    begin try
        if @trancount = 0
            begin transaction
        else
            save transaction [myload];

EXEC MAIN_procedure

lbexit:
        if @trancount = 0   
            commit;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
 declare @error int, @severity varchar(4000), @estate varchar(55), @procedure varchar (55), @eline varchar (255), @emessage varchar (4000), @edate date;
  SELECT  @error=ERROR_NUMBER(),

         @severity=ERROR_SEVERITY(),

         @estate=ERROR_STATE() ,

         @procedure=ERROR_PROCEDURE(),

         @eline=ERROR_LINE(),

         @emessage= ERROR_MESSAGE() ,

         @edate=GETDATE();


  if XACT_STATE() = -1
            rollback;
        if XACT_STATE() = 1 and @trancount = 0
            rollback
        if XACT_STATE() = 1 and @trancount > 0
            rollback transaction [mytransaction];

 INSERT INTO myErrorTable
 SELECT  ProcedureName= 'myload',
@error,@severity, @estate, @procedure, @eline, @emessage,  @edate;


END CATCH
END
```

Seems to work so far so thank you all for your help!

Comment: Wrap the code in a transaction and roll it back on any failure condition.

Comment: If you have a failed transaction you need to roll it back *before* you can continue with SQL operations such as logging errors. Typically in a try/catch block you test whether there is an open transaction and if there is roll it back. Then do any error handling.

Comment: Thanks Dale. I've  put  IF @@trancount > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION before INSERT but I'm still getting the error

Comment: What actual error are you using to test this? Some errors are un-recoverable and therefore won't let you continue no matter what.

Comment: simple ones: wrong column datatype or table's name

Comment: I think they might well count as un-recoverable. Try a failure to convert a string to a datetime.

Comment: I moved the 'transaction rollback' to outer procedure and it works. At least seems to work, I'm still testing it!

Answer (score 2):

Transaction block will `ROLLBACK` all the transactions, if any one of the transaction fails inside the transaction block.

Don't use `TRUNCATE` inside the transaction block, because truncate statements never rolled back.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION [Tran1]

BEGIN TRY

  INSERT INTO Your_Table (Col1, Col2)
  VALUES ....

  UPDATE Your_Table 
  SET [Col1] = .......
  WHERE ........

  COMMIT TRANSACTION [Tran1]

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [Tran1]

END CATCH
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Savepoint feature to save part of the transaction, i.e., saving results to staging table. I have utilized Remus Rusunu nested transaction approach with save points. You can read the same [here](http://rusanu.com/2009/06/11/exception-handling-and-nested-transactions/)

```sql
declare @trancount int;
    set @trancount = @@trancount;

BeginTry

if @trancount = 0
   BEGIN TRANSACTION

INSERT INTO StagingTable... 

SAVE TRANSACTION StagingTableInsertion


DELETE FROM FactTable WHERE <CONDITION>...

INSERT INTO FactTable...
SELECT * FROM StagingTable

IF @tranCount = 0
    COMMIT TRANSACTION

EndTry
BeginCatch

declare @error int, @message varchar(4000), @xstate int;
        select @error = ERROR_NUMBER(), @message = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @xstate = XACT_STATE();
        if @xstate = -1
            rollback;
        if @xstate = 1 and @trancount = 0
            rollback
        if @xstate = 1 and @trancount > 0
            rollback transaction StagingTableInsertion;

        raiserror ('usp_my_procedure_name: %d: %s', 16, 1, @error, @message) ;

EndCatch
```

[Read more on SavePoints on mssqltips](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5538/understanding-sql-server-transaction-savepoints/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `try/catch` statement and `raiserror` to return the control back to main procedure in the catch rollback the transaction.

But I may suggest instead of playing with the fact table, create a second staging table like 'staging_table_2' and manipulate the data in this staging, you can refer to fact tables in joins and then use a simple merge to populate the fact table.

This way you will always be sure data in your fact is clean and failures is not impacting any data inconsistency.

Comment: agree 'throw' is a recommended over 'raiseerror' now.